# Select audio from second input file for ffmpeg movie overlay

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm working from [this example from the ffmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20mosaic%20out%20of%20several%20input%20videos)

```
ffmpeg
    -i 1.avi -i 2.avi -i 3.avi -i 4.avi
    -filter_complex "
        nullsrc=size=640x480 [base];
        [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [upperleft];
        [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [upperright];
        [2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [lowerleft];
        [3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [lowerright];
        [base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1];
        [tmp1][upperright] overlay=shortest=1:x=320 [tmp2];
        [tmp2][lowerleft] overlay=shortest=1:y=240 [tmp3];
        [tmp3][lowerright] overlay=shortest=1:x=320:y=240
    "
    -c:v libx264 output.mkv
```

The problem is that it always takes the audio from the *first movie*. How can I, for example, have the audio come from the second movie?

Adding [Channelmap](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#channelmap) within the `-filter_complex` seems like the way to go, but I can't figure out how to reference tracks in the movies.

I tried variations on this:

```
channelmap=map=0.0.0=1.0.0|0.0.1=1.0.1
```

But it gives syntax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`-map` option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options). Otherwise you're going to be limited to the default [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) behavior which may not choose what you want.

#### Example

This will map the audio from the second input (`2.avi`):

```
-map 1:a
```

- Since `ffmpeg` starts counting from 0 the first input id is 0, the second is 1, the third is 2, etc.
- If the second input has multiple audio streams this will map them all. If, for example, you only want the fourth audio stream from the second input, then you can use `-map 1:a:3`.

#### With filtering

I tend to explicitly tell `ffmpeg` what stream to use to avoid ambiguity instead of relying on defaults. So your command can look like this example below:

```
ffmpeg
    -i 1.avi -i 2.avi -i 3.avi -i 4.avi
    -filter_complex "
        nullsrc=size=640x480 [base];
        [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [upperleft];
        [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [upperright];
        [2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [lowerleft];
        [3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [lowerright];
        [base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1];
        [tmp1][upperright] overlay=shortest=1:x=320 [tmp2];
        [tmp2][lowerleft] overlay=shortest=1:y=240 [tmp3];
        [tmp3][lowerright] overlay=shortest=1:x=320:y=240[v]
    "
    -map "[v]" -map 1:a -c:v libx264 -shortest output.mkv
```

- Notice the two instances of the `[v]` and the `1:a`: these will map the video from the filtergraph, and the audio from the second input (`2.avi`).
- I added `-shortest` to make sure the output ends when the shortest input ends (either `[v]` or `1:a`).